# Why show button is changing style each time i click it

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-5

I'm new to javascript
And I'm attempting to style the "show more" button. 
I added a text and a down arrow under it, but when I click it, the show less button "I don't know how to style it" appears with hidden content, then when I click it again, the show more button appears with no icon or style.

```js
function toggleText() {
  var showMoreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var buttonText = document.getElementById("moreButton");
  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "inline";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "inline";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
}
```

```css
.pink {
  color: #FF7B5F;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}

#moreButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<span id="startpoint"></span>
<span id="more">
    <div class="clients BRANDING col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="filter-container">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="./images/filter/logo" alt="Logo">
          <figcaption class="product-desc"><P>text</P></figcaption>
          <figcaption class="product-desc2"><h4>text</h4></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  </span>
<button onclick="toggleText()" id="moreButton">
    <p class="pink">Show More</p> 
    <img class="more" src="./images/downarrow" alt="arrow">
  </button>
```

Comment: Divs are not valid children of spans.

Comment: You're changing the innerHTML of the button.  However the button contains other elements which get deleted when you set the innerHTML.  Some of those deleted elements are what style your button.

Comment: so how can i fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you overriding the p tag iner the button. Use this selector `var buttonText = document.querySelector("#moreButton p");` Like that:

```js
function toggleText() {
  var showMoreText = document.getElementById("more");  
  var buttonText = document.querySelector("#moreButton p");
  
  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "inline";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";    
    buttonText.classList.remove('green')
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "inline";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
    buttonText.classList.add('green')
  }
}
```

```css
.pink {
  color: #FF7B5F;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}

#moreButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<span id="startpoint"></span> 
<span id="more">
    <div class="clients BRANDING col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="filter-container">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="./images/filter/logo" alt="Logo">
          <figcaption class="product-desc"><P>text</P></figcaption>
          <figcaption class="product-desc2"><h4>text</h4></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  </span>
<button onclick="toggleText()" id="moreButton">
    <p class="pink">Show More</p> 
    <img class="more" src="./images/downarrow" alt="arrow">
  </button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maik can i ask how to can i style the show less now ?

Comment: @aliharas You welcome! You can change the style by classlist. i updated my answer. `buttonText.classList.add('green')`and `buttonText.classList.remove('green')`

Answer (score 0):

Please try it. code is not proper. You have kept dive within the span.

```js
function toggleText() {
  var showMoreText = document.getElementById("more");
  var buttonText = document.getElementById("moreButton");
  var arrowBtn = document.getElementById("arrowButton");
  
  if (startpoint.style.display === "none") {
    showMoreText.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "inline";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show More";
    arrowBtn.style.display = "inline";
  } else {
    showMoreText.style.display = "inline";
    arrowBtn.style.display = "none";
    startpoint.style.display = "none";
    buttonText.innerHTML = "Show Less";
  }
}
```

```css
.pink {
  color: #FF7B5F;
}

#more {
  display: none;
}

#moreButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<span id="startpoint"></span>
<span id="more">
    <div class="clients BRANDING col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="filter-container">
          <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="./images/filter/logo" alt="Logo">
          <figcaption class="product-desc"><P>text</P></figcaption>
          <figcaption class="product-desc2"><h4>text</h4></figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  </span>
<button onclick="toggleText()">
    <span class="pink" id="moreButton">Show More</span> 
    <img class="more" src="./images/downarrow" alt="arrow" id="arrowButton">
  </button>
```